# How to get the detailed runtime per train_step using tf.keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

how could I get the detailed runtime of each train_step through the tf.keras when training?? Though I know adding call backs into model.fit() is able to return epoch time, but I need to know:
prediction_time
loss_calculate_time
grad_time
grad_apply_time
update_time 
Such operations above As what we do using custom training loop like this:

```py
  def train_step(inputs):
    images, labels = inputs

    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
      predictions = model(images, training=True)
      loss = compute_loss(labels, predictions)

    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))

    train_accuracy.update_state(labels, predictions)
    return loss
```

Comment: You can get loss and metrics with callbacks. You can't get any execution time. But you can write callbacks for "batch execution time" (not below this).

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement can be satisfied using `Profiler` Feature offered by `Tensorflow`.

The Statistics of every operation during `Training Step` can be captured using `Tensorflow Profiler` and the same can be visualized in the `Profile` tab of `Tensorboard`.

Since you are interested in knowing the execution times of different operations occurring during Training Time, it can be visualized in the **`tensorflow_stats`** drop down of `Profiler`, as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

Screenshot of the Sample Operations (only 17 are visible in the screenshot out of 64) that can be visualized using `Profiler` in `Tensorboard` is shown below:

[image]

For more information about this awesome feature, `Tensorflow Profiler`, please refer [this Guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/profiler), [this Tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/tensorboard_profiling_keras) and this [Dev Summit Youtube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pXHAQIhhMhI).

Hope this helps. Happy Learning!!